# React Native - Animate bottom tab bar with scroll

Tags: react-native, animation

In my react native project, I want bottom tabBar to be shown on screen, as you scroll upwards with your finger, say 200 offset y, the tabBar hides with animation, and when you scroll down, again, say 200 offset y, it shows the tabBar again.

I am using createBottomTabNavigator. I am able to show/hide bottom bar without animation.

I have tried

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/888#issuecomment-299600368

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/958

Below is my code

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        const params = navigation.state.params;
        return {
          tabBarVisible: params && params.tabBarVisible,
          animationEnabled: true,
        }
      },
```

How can I animate the bottom bar as user scrolls the list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a solution?  I also encountered this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bottom navigation with animation, you can use the createMaterialTopTabNavigator and simply set the tabBarPosition.

[For detail information about **createMaterialTopTabNavigator**](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html#docsNav)

Comment: I wanted to position my the `MaterialTopTabNavigator` but didn't get the chance to see the docs. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You can use  ***tabBarPosition*** of ***TabNavigatorConfig***,which means  Position of the tab bar, can be 'top' or 'bottom', default is top.

Comment: Not working. tab bar is showing but not animating with scroll

Comment: Could you share code of your Scroll Component? (Your scroll view, flat list or what else you are using) I think that you have a mistake about connecting between scroll and createMaterialTopTabNavigator. Maybe you want to check ***react-navigation-collapsible***.  [link]https://snack.expo.io/@benevbright/react-navigation-collapsible[link]

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share code. The implementation I want is same as LinkedIn bottom tab bar in android app.